# Template type deduction involving nested template parameters and defaults

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

class CDelegateCore {};

class CDelegate : public CDelegateCore {};

class CEvent
{
   private:

      /// Simple empty enumeration used for enable_if test.
      enum class enabler_t {};

      template<typename T>
      using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<T::value, enabler_t>::type;

   public:

      CEvent() {}
      ~CEvent() {}

      void operator += (CDelegateCore* func) {}

      template<typename T, typename Deleter, EnableIf<std::is_base_of<CDelegateCore, T>> = enabler_t{}>
      void operator += (std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> const& func) { *this += func.get(); }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<CDelegate> testdel;
    // ... initialize testdel ...

    CEvent EVENT;
    EVENT += testdel;
}
```

The goal here is that when I have a `CDelegate` owned by a `std::unique_ptr`, that the `+=` overload in `CEvent` utilizing `std::enable_if` will be invoked and the template parameters inside `std::unique_ptr` will be deduced.

This code works fine in GCC and Clang, but in MSVC12 it fails. It is unable to resolve the function. Can anyone tell me why? I originally didn't have a template argument for the unique_ptr deleter, and it worked, but I'm not sure what the rules are in C++ regarding type deduction with defaulted nested template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain of this, but I believe this is because of the lack of expression SFINAE support in VS2013. You can get the code to work on VS2013 (and gcc and clang) if you move the `enable_if` expression to the return type of `operator+=`

```
template<typename T, typename Deleter>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CDelegateCore, T>::value>::type
  operator += (std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> const& func) { *this += func.get(); }
```

You can use your `EnableIf` alias by changing the second template argument to `void`, or just use `std::enable_if_t` (requires `-std=c++1y` on gcc and clang).

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bf954899c449599)

Comment: I wasn't able to find documentation from Microsoft on the lack of proper SFINAE support. Where did you find your information?

Comment: @void.pointer [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) table shows neither VS2013 nor VS14 support expression SFINAE. But as I mentioned, I'm not sure this is an effect of that. I'd have expected a `decltype` expression being used for SFINAE to not work on VS2013, but not your example. It could be the rest of their SFINAE support is not complete as well, or at the very least, buggy.

Answer (score 0):

VS2013 supports SFINAE or at least most part of it.
Change

```
template<typename T, typename Deleter, EnableIf<std::is_base_of<CDelegateCore, T>> = enabler_t{}>
```

to

```
template<typename T, typename Deleter, class = EnableIf<std::is_base_of<CDelegateCore, T>>>
```

Comment: What is the class= syntax?

Comment: Unnamed template argument with default type.